# Building report using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting

What are the best practices for building a report that shows data from several tables and which can be searchable by some fields, e.g by date?

The structure of the report is following:

```
                Today    Yesterday  Last 7 days     All
New Users         0         10        20           1000
Sold Products     11        21        31           25000
```

All I can think of is just building the report with stored procedure and OUTPUT parameters, it works quite fine, but it is a tedious work both on a SQL Server side and in application. I just don't know any other way of doing this.

Maybe it can be done by using cursor or using different stored procedures or some other technique. Can you please navigate me to a better approach? I appreciate any help.

Here is my current approach

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Statistics
    @DateFrom datetime = NULL, 
    @DateTo datetime = NULL,

    @UsersRegisteredToday int = 0 OUTPUT,
    @UsersRegisteredYesterday int = 0 OUTPUT, 
    @UsersRegisteredLastSevenDays int = 0 OUTPUT,
    @UsersRegisteredTotal int = 0 OUTPUT,
    @UsersRegisteredDate int = 0 OUTPUT,

    @SoldProductsToday int = 0 OUTPUT,
    @SoldProductsYesterday int = 0 OUTPUT, 
    @SoldProductsLastSevenDays int = 0 OUTPUT,
    @SoldProductsTotal int = 0 OUTPUT,
    @SoldProductsDate int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

--------------------- REGISTERED USERS -----------------------
IF (@DateFrom IS NOT NULL OR @DateTo IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @UsersRegisteredDate = COUNT(*)
        FROM [User] u
        WHERE DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(D, 0, u.Date), 0) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
    END
ELSE IF @DateFrom IS NULL AND @DateTo IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @UsersRegisteredToday = COUNT(DISTINCT u.idUser)
        FROM [User] u
        LEFT JOIN [Order] e ON u.idUser = e.idUser
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), u.Date) = 0

        SELECT @UtilizadoresYesterday = COUNT(DISTINCT u.idUser)
        FROM [User] u
        LEFT JOIN [Order] e ON u.idUser = e.idUser
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), u.Date) = -1

        SELECT @UsersRegisteredLastSevenDays = COUNT(DISTINCT u.idUser)
        FROM [User] u
        LEFT JOIN [Order] e ON u.idUser = e.idUser
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), u.Date) >= -7

        SELECT @UsersRegisteredTotal = COUNT(DISTINCT u.idUser)
        FROM [User] u
        LEFT JOIN [Order] e ON u.idUser = e.idUser
    END

--------------------- SOLD PRODUCTS --------------------------
IF (@DateFrom IS NOT NULL OR @DateTo IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SoldProductsDate = COUNT(*)
        FROM [Order] e
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2
              AND
              DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(D, 0, e.Date), 0) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
    END
ELSE IF @DateFrom IS NULL AND @DateTo IS NULL
    BEGIN

        SELECT @SoldProductsToday = COUNT(*) 
        FROM [Order] e 
        LEFT JOIN [User] u ON e.idUser = u.idUser
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2 AND DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), e.Date) = 0

        SELECT @SoldProductsYesterday = COUNT(*)
        FROM [Order] e
        LEFT JOIN [User] u ON e.idUser = u.idUser
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2 AND DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), e.Date) = -1

        SELECT @SoldProductsLastSevenDays = COUNT(*)
        FROM [Order] e
        LEFT JOIN [User] u ON e.idUser = u.idUser
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2 AND DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), e.Date) >= -7

        SELECT @SoldProductsTotal = COUNT(*)
        FROM [Order] e
        LEFT JOIN [User] u ON e.idUser = u.idUser
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2
    END
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using output params I would create a temporary table in the sp and insert the data into that and then once all the data is there do a select on it.

Creating the report itself should then be fairly easy if you use either a grid in your application or as Charleh suggested the better option of using SSRS. You can then embed the SSRS report viewer into your application.

Comment: As an alternative, you can also have multiple data sources in an SSRS report, so you could write multiple `SELECT` statements, one for each table to get your data, and then just add several sections to the report to display the data, saving the need for temp tables. I rarely find a use for temp tables - I try to use a decent set of indexes and if really needed, use a table variable instead of a temp table. Temp tables do have their place though!

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using SSRS? SQL Reporting Services, it comes bundled with SQL.. am I barking up the wrong tree here?

I'd consider using this to create reports since it's a reporting tool

You'd just write your data 'SELECT' with some parameters

e.g.

```
SELECT SomeValue, SomeOtherValue FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeValue = @SomeParameter
```

The parameters are configurable etc... have you not heard of/seen/used it before?

e.g. here's one of our reports - would only take up to an hour to write this report really...

[image: one of our reports]

Comment: Ok, this looks like a fine solution and I used Crystal Reports back in my days in university. But I assume SSRS is not provided in some particular versions of SQL server. And using reporting tools maybe too much for my task, I seek something easier that can be used in web or desktop applications on a daily basis without any tools. Thank you sir for suggestion!

Comment: Nope, it's provided with all versions of SQL, express included. It's also lightweight and I wouldn't say 'too much' for your task. It's similar to Crystal but easy to write reports in. The server will usually already have SSRS installed if a full install was done. What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Additionally, you can have multi-valued parameters, and drop downs, so you could easily condense your report options into a set of easily selectable parameters. Also the reports all run from the report server, you can schedule delivery etc using subscriptions. Basically most of the time if I want a simple report that's got a few parameters, I'd use SSRS over writing some sproc...

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [table-valued UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Statistics
(
    @DateFrom datetime = NULL, 
    @DateTo datetime = NULL
)
RETURNS @Report TABLE(
    Today int,
    Yesterday,
    LastSevenDays,
    Total int,
    [Date] int)
AS    
BEGIN
--------------------- REGISTERED USERS -----------------------
IF (@DateFrom IS NOT NULL OR @DateTo IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT @Report
        SELECT 0,0,0,0,COUNT(*)
        FROM [User] u
        WHERE DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(D, 0, u.Date), 0) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo;
--------------------- SOLD PRODUCTS --------------------------        
        INSERT @Report
        SELECT 0,0,0,0,COUNT(*)
        FROM [Order] e
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2
              AND
              DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(D, 0, e.Date), 0) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo;

    END
    ELSE IF @DateFrom IS NULL AND @DateTo IS NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @UsersRegisteredToday int,
                @UsersRegisteredYesterday int,
                @UsersRegisteredLastSevenDays int,
                @UsersRegisteredTotal int;

        SELECT @UsersRegisteredToday = COUNT(DISTINCT u.idUser)
        FROM [User] u
        LEFT JOIN [Order] e ON u.idUser = e.idUser
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), u.Date) = 0

        SELECT @UtilizadoresYesterday = COUNT(DISTINCT u.idUser)
        FROM [User] u
        LEFT JOIN [Order] e ON u.idUser = e.idUser
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), u.Date) = -1

        SELECT @UsersRegisteredLastSevenDays = COUNT(DISTINCT u.idUser)
        FROM [User] u
        LEFT JOIN [Order] e ON u.idUser = e.idUser
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), u.Date) >= -7

        SELECT @UsersRegisteredTotal = COUNT(DISTINCT u.idUser)
        FROM [User] u
        LEFT JOIN [Order] e ON u.idUser = e.idUser

        INSERT @Report VALUES(@UsersRegisteredToday,
                              @UsersRegisteredYesterday,
                              @UsersRegisteredLastSevenDays,
                              @UsersRegisteredTotal,
                              0);
        --------------------- SOLD PRODUCTS --------------------------

        DECLARE @SoldProductsToday int,
                @SoldProductsYesterday int,
                @SoldProductsLastSevenDays int,
                @SoldProductsTotal int;

        SELECT @SoldProductsToday = COUNT(*) 
        FROM [Order] e 
        LEFT JOIN [User] u ON e.idUser = u.idUser
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2 AND DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), e.Date) = 0

        SELECT @SoldProductsYesterday = COUNT(*)
        FROM [Order] e
        LEFT JOIN [User] u ON e.idUser = u.idUser
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2 AND DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), e.Date) = -1

        SELECT @SoldProductsLastSevenDays = COUNT(*)
        FROM [Order] e
        LEFT JOIN [User] u ON e.idUser = u.idUser
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2 AND DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), e.Date) >= -7

        SELECT @SoldProductsTotal = COUNT(*)
        FROM [Order] e
        LEFT JOIN [User] u ON e.idUser = u.idUser
        WHERE e.idPaymentState = 2

        INSERT @Report VALUES(@SoldProductsToday,
                              @SoldProductsYesterday,
                              @SoldProductsLastSevenDays,
                              @SoldProductsTotal,
                              0);
    END
    RETURN
 END
```