# How to build database reports using multiple remote databases

Tags: database, web, reporting

Does anyone have experience building database reports - doesn't matter which database - i just want design ideas - for a system that is made up of many separate, but identical databases? 
I cannot "combine" all databases into one.  They must be separate.
But the structure is identical across all databases...

I need to build a web interface that will allow a user to get a "global" report that will query all databases and build one combined report.

Do you have any comments on how the model would look like? or anything you think i need to beware of?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have first hand experience with cross database reports, my experience comes from a product the company i work for sells which can create reports from multiple databases, from your description i believe you require something of the "combine" tables kind, in this case i recommend you to detect the tables used in the query, and unify them in a single temporary intermediary database, for example Access, SQL Server CE or SQLite and then run the query against this temporary database or table.

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are Microsoft SQL Server, then using SQL Server Reporting Services seems like a good solution.  The software for the report generation / display is bundled along with the database software.

It gives you a web interface, where you can configure 'data sources' from any number of remote databases, and combine data from these sources into reports.  It is user friendly and you can do all the report design / configuration through the web interface without having to write any code.

some references :
[Building report using SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857446/building-report-using-sql-server-stored-procedure)

http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/11/10/reporting-on-data-from-stored-procedures-part-1/